# rails many to many model query problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

there have two model Product & Gift ,here is the relationship

Product belongs to many Gifts
one Gift category has many products

so they have a assocation table named gift_products

how can i write a code achieve this sql

select top 1 from gift_products where product_id=1 and gift_id=2

the meaning is i want check,is a specific record already in the assocation table,i'm new on rails ,

i tried use

```
rails g model GiftProduct
GiftProduct.find_by_sql("select top 1 from gift_products where product_id=1 and gift_id=2")
```

to generate a model to treat assocation table as operate like usual,but it seems dosen't work, i use sqlite3 as dev db .

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Show us your code and what precisely isn't doing what you expect, if you can. Finally, don't forget that you can always use `Model.find_by_sql('select ...')` if you can't find the perfect helper...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
GiftProduct.where(:product_id => 1, :gift_id => 1).first
```

return `nil` if no such record, otherwise the gift_product record.